# how to write x2 (x-square) in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am creating a calculator app and i want to display x<sup>2</sup> in button content, in XAML.

I have tried the `<sup>` tag but it's giving an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want the text (Content) of the button to have x² written?? Then you simply want superscript character 2.

Then you can just copy and paste the text above ;)

here is the list of unicode characters-

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/No/list.htm

Comment: Can u pls tell me how to write x to the power of n

Comment: @SaleemKhan xⁿ you can search on google for superscript a,b,c.... or anything you want in superscript

Answer (score 6):

You can set button text to x² - `"x\u00b2"`

Comment: Can u pls tell me how to write x to the power of n

Comment: @SaleemKhan `\u207F` - http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/superscripts_and_subscripts/list.htm

Answer (score 2):

That should work:

```
<Button Content="x²"/>
```